# Linking a connection to SQL Server database in ASP.NET (creating signup page)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Confused to what I've done wrong, in the `web.config` file, I have added

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" 
        connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-8TA96FC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PersciptionPal;Intergrated Security=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and in my signup page, I wrote this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace PerscriptionManager
{
    public partial class WebForm5 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        // sign up button 
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write("<script>alert('Testing');</script>");
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }// checking if the connection is actually connected to the database

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User_Signup_tbl (Full_name, dob, Contact_Num, Email, County, City, Postcode, Full_Address, User_ID, Password, Account_Status,) VALUES (@Full_name, @dob, @Contact_Num, @Email, @County, @City, @Postcode, @Full_Address, @User_ID, @Password, @Account_Status,)", con);

                // place holders must add values 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Full_name", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_Num", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", TextBox7.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Full_Address", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", TextBox8.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox10.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending"); // hard code as first time login 

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    // execute the code and fill database 
                con.Close(); // close connection 

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Activated. Please Login Using New Details');</script>");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script> alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>"); // alert if error appears // dynamic message 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing some research online I really cant see where I have gone wrong here when the button is clicked nothing happens and the database is not updated.

Cheers for the help :)

Comment: Side note, use `using` statements to dispose objects when done, dont use `AddWithValue` (doing so will infer the type), use `Add` and specify the type, length etc. and please don't store plain text passwords...

Comment: Also theres an extra (2x)`,` in your command at the end and where you define the columns. You should be getting an error about syntax...

Comment: If you're concerned that your button isn't getting clicked, please provide the relevant aspx markup. Please review the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Possibly just a **typo** in your connection string?? `Intergrated Security` - this should be `Integrated Security` (i-n-t-e-g-r- - no "r" between the "e" and "g") ....

Comment: Also, Perscription is spelled 2 ways, in the namespace and the conn string's Initial Catalog. And "Perscription" is not a word; you might want to look it up.

Comment: Are the parameters in your sql matching correctly i can see account_ status is Account_Status uppercase?

Comment: And you have a leading ',' character in ur sql

Comment: Issue fixed it was a simple spelling mistake, the problem always seems bigger than what I expect. Thank you for your input and help

Answer (score 0):

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User_Signup_tbl (Full_name, dob, Contact_Num, Email, County, City, Postcode, Full_Address, User_ID, Password, Account_Status) VALUES (@Full_name, @dob, @Contact_Num, @Email, @County, @City, @PostCode, @Full_Address, @User_ID, @Password, @account_status)", con);
```

The parameter names passed must match in the sql
And i dont think u need the leading comma at the end of the sql parenthes